# responsive navigation toggle menu issue

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have been working on my portfolio website and I can't seem to get my responsive navigation working properly.

The normal navigation works fine, but the responsive navigation toggle menu presents issues on the mobile version. When the toggle is clicked it changes from the menu icon to the X icon, but the drop-down navigation menu doesn't appear.

I have been trying to solve this issue and cannot seem to find a solution. Any feedback would be appreciated, HTML, CSS & JavaScript below.

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $('span.nav-btn').click(function() {
    $('ul.nav').toggle();
  })

  $(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() > 660) {
      $('ul.nav').removeAttr('style')
    }
  })
});


function myFunction(x) {
  x.classList.toggle("change");
}
```

```css
nav {
  letter-spacing: 1.9px;
  float: right;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 60px 150px 0px 0px;
}

.nav>li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav>li>a {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 18px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav>li>a:hover {
  color: #c3dbc5;
}

.nav .current {
  font-weight: bolder;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  nav {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
  }
  .nav {
    display: none;
  }
  ul {
    padding: 0px;
  }
  .nav>li {
    margin-top: 50px;
    padding: 15px 0px 0px 15px;
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none !important;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .nav>li>a {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  .container_nav {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    padding: 50px;
    margin-top: 0px;
  }
  .container_nav.change {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .bar1,
  .bar2,
  .bar3 {
    width: 35px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #333;
    margin: 6px 0;
    transition: 0.4s;
  }
  .change .bar1 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  }
  .change .bar2 {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .change .bar3 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  }
}
```

```html
<nav role="navigation" id="nav">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="index.htm" title="Work">Work</a></li>
    <li><a href="aboutme.htm" class="current" title="About">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="files/resume.pdf" target="_blank" title="Resume">Resume</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.htm" title="Contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="container_nav" onclick="myFunction(this)">

    <div class="bar1"></div>
    <div class="bar2"></div>
    <div class="bar3"></div>

    <span class="nav-btn"></span>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You shouldn't use both event handlers and inline function calls. Keep JavaScript out of your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change a couple of things in your code to get things done.

1. Get your nav hamburger icon out of the nav container.
2. The comment says it right, remove the onclick function from the `container_nav` div.
3. Replace your entire jquery code with

   $(document).ready(function () {
   $("div.container_nav").click(function () {
   $("div.container_nav").toggleClass("change");
   $("ul.nav").toggleClass("toggle-menu");
   });
   });
4. You're adding `.change` both the time to the `container_nav` which isn't toggling the menu because nothing changes at `.nav` so rename your `.container_nav.change` class to `.nav.toggle-menu`.

The comment section is always open if you're stuck again.

Comment: Thanks for the help and information. 

I have updated my code and the drop-down navigation li now presents when the toggle is clicked. However, when the toggle is clicked and changes to the X icon, it moves position to underneath the drop-down navigation li. I would like for the X icon to be fixed to the top right of the screen, where the menu icon is located before clicking.

Comment: Well that shouldn't happen if your hamburger icon is out of the 'nav' container. I suppose you want to position icon to the right, for that first move the icon out and give it a wrapper div with class 'hamburger-icon' and 'position: relative;'. Remove all the styles from '.container_nav' in the media query and add 'width: auto;
    margin: 2rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;'